# bootstrap nav tabs htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got problem with my .htaccess while i using bootstrap nav tabs `

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
   <li class="active"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">page1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#pane2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">page2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#pane3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">page3</a></li> 
   <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">page4</a></li>   
</ul>
```

I need to change URL to www.domain.com/index/page1 or page2 ... but when i switching between them URL doesn't changed. And when use my .htaccess file nav tabs stop working. What should i type in a .htaccess file to get this URL or use script which i get ID name to the URL and then use this rewrite rule?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index index.php#pane1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> You will find the error

> The requested URL /registration/js/jquery.min.js was not found on this server.

it is because of  our url may like  `www.example.com/#tab1` original is working 
`www.example.com/mydir/#tab1` is not valid, It should be  written whole bootstrap css and whole bootstrap path to solve this issue.